# A bad boot command made my system inaccessible

Tags: boot, command-line, startup, init.d

Okay, so I made a really stupid mistake.

I made a shell script that runs `nodemon /path/to/nodejs/file` and added it to the boot process via `update-rc.d mystartup.sh defaults 99`, thinking I could use this to automatically start my Node.js server on boot in case/when I restart my server.

`node` and `nodemon` are commands that, when run, change the command context so that I can run Node-related commands. I can then exit out of the process by pressing `Ctrl + C`.

But when I boot, it's like the machine hasn't registered my I/O devices and I can't type, so I can't quit (or execute any other command). Nodemon just runs.

Is there some other way I can remove this startup command? It's farfetched, but I really screwed it up and I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: live dvd. edit/remove the file you messed up ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a live CD or USB. Boot from it, choose "Try Ubuntu" and then mount your installed system's drive. For example, if the `/` drive of your installed system is `/dev/sda1`, you would want to do

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/oldroot
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/oldroot
```

Once you have done that, you should be able to navigate to the `/etc/rcX.d` directories and delete the relevant links. These directories (one for each runlevel) conatin links to scripts located in `/etc/init.d`. So, once you've removed the links, you may as well go and remove the script that you created in the `/etc/init.d` directory.

Once you've done that, reboot and you should be OK.

Comment: It's Ubuntu Server, so there's no "Try Ubuntu." What should I do when I get to the main menu? I don't want to install Ubuntu Server, I'm afraid I'd wipe everything. Do I run "Rescue a broken system"?

Comment: @MMiller you need to use a _live_ CD. One that lets you boot into a live session. I've never installed the server edition. If that won't let you, just download a desktop ISO or, use a different Linux distribution. There's no need for it to be the same one. For example, you could try [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) which is a 50MB image and will also allow you to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was having difficulty running DSL (something weird about how my hard drive is configured), but I managed to get into a root command line from Recovery Mode, get access to the disk, and delete the shell file.